What can reduce the deflection window in Sekiro?
The fextralife wiki states that the deflection window is 12 frames, or 0.2 seconds. It mentions that guarding and failing to deflect reduces this window but doesn't quantify this. There's no other mention of the window shrinking, which doesn't match my experience.
Are there any other sources of the window shrinking?
The two I have in mind are rapid attacks that come in under the maximum deflect window (i.e. two attacks in 0.1 seconds). My experience is that if you try to immediately deflect the second attack, it will simply guard and not deflect.
The other is being hit with certain non-damaging moves. When fighting Owl, he has a kick-and-jump move that leads to him tossing a bunch of shuriken. If I deflect the kick, deflecting the shuriken is trivial. If I get hit by it, then I merely guard the shuriken. Other enemies have similar "stun" moves, e.g. the Ashina Castle fencers can punch you, which also seems to mess up deflecting the followup attack.
Do these, or anything else, reduce or eliminate the deflect window, or am I misunderstanding what's going on during combat?
